# Programs run (gedit, system monitor, etc) in TightVNC workspace open on local workspace instead of VNC workspace

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, tightvnc, workspace, vnc-viewer

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and have install TightVNC using:

```
sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
sudo apt install tightvncserver
vncserver
<input password>
<verify password>
vncserver -kill :1
```

I then modified the ~.vnc/startup to say:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Inside of /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service I put:

```
[Unit]
Description=TightVNC server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=jim
#PAMName=login
PIDFile=/home/jim/.vnc/%H:1.pid
#ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1680x1050
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I set it to run at boot

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable --now vncserver@1
```

It starts can I can connect to the VNC session fine. I can open a terminal window but if I try and open something like gedit or any other application it opens on the local workspace as if I was sitting at the computer rather than in my VNC session.  I cannot figure out what to change to get around this odd behavior and have not been able to find anything online where someone else has had this happen to them.

Comment: I would reword the title.  These are not "TightVNC programs".

Comment: Are you connecting to the vnc server from the same machine? Are you using ssh? Ssh has x11 forwarding support, and if you're on the same machine a misconfigured DISPLAY environment variable could cause this

Answer (score 0):

Certain programs (mostly those part of GNOME) use "single instance" mode, where the app tries to find an existing instance of itself on D-Bus (or some other IPC system) and tells to just open a new window on wherever that app is already running. If the first instance of gedit is already running on display :0, then whenever you run `gedit` again and it issues an "open a new window" request to the existing instance, that window will also show up on :0.

(This is similar in concept to emacs/emacsclient, or urxvtd/urxvtc. It is also done by Firefox and other browsers.)

Some programs also extend this to the *initial* launch as well. That is, instead of the `gedit` command directly running the app, it will still use D-Bus even if there *isn't* an already running instance there – it will have dbus-daemon start the "real thing", which will connect to whatever $DISPLAY dbus-daemon currently knows.

In both cases, the best way to avoid it is to make sure a **separate D-Bus session bus** is started for your entire TightVNC X11 session:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
dbus-run-session startxfce4 &
```

This will make sure Xfce will have its own $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, with its own namespace of running programs and its own knowledge of DISPLAY and other environment.

This is not ideal, though, as some session components aren't fully safe to have two instances running, but in practice it shouldn't really cause problems.

Comment: Some program (e.g. gnome-terminal) even relies on environment (DISPLAY) imported to systemd (and start systemd-service "server" via dbus), which means it's designed with single-X/DISPLAY-per-user in mind. You literally have to make it use "less" of dbus and have some wrapper script that starts systemd service with a template (@) and systemctl so that it gets the correct `DISPLAY`. (And not even all programs would have that `--app-id` switch like gnome-terminal does that makes it possible.) It's awful :(

Comment: @TomYan: gnome-terminal doesn't rely on systemd directly (not for startup, anyway) – that's just dbus-daemon's own integration with systemd, i.e. starting bus-activated services as systemd services when possible. If you start a new dbus-daemon instance with no org.freedesktop.systemd in it, it'll fork the bus-activated services directly like in the past.